# How do you decide whether to dictate, type out or hand-write a piece of writing?

Tags: typing, handwriting

How do you decide whether to dictate, type out or hand-write a piece of writing?

I have always had a minor passion for writing, and I enjoy the process of settings ideas out and slowly filling them out, trimming them down or deleting them altogether. This is easiest to do on a computer - so easy to cut, copy paste, organise, Google and re-write. Being able to touch type makes this process an almost organic extension of my consciousness.

Hand writing is a different sort of pleasure. I used to get lost in handwriting in a similar way, but often I felt like my thinking slows down to match my hand-writing speed. I would re-write and draw lines to indicate which bit is meant to go in between which other bits. It was hard to transcribe my writing, but fulfilling because it was a conscious editing step.

In the last decade, the only hand-writing I do now is writing meeting notes at work - but even then I love organising the notes as I go, and doodling! Building up small doodles to fill a page feels good too.

Now I have an iPad with a keyboard case that feels comfortable to use for short periods; I can almost thumb-touch type on my iPhone without looking at the keys.. I can easily spend the entire train trip home just writing out a message or blog post. And drawing apps make me feel like an artist, even though I blanch at every creation. :)

And then I discovered Dragon Dictation on my iPhone - and how it gets about 70% of my words correct.. mangling names but getting the bulk of it right. I find myself stopping and starting a lot - both when I type and when I dictate into my phone. But during dictation, the pauses seem more pregnant, more expectant and I find myself stressing out at being unable to immediately go back and change a word or fix up a capitalisation. I can get out short bursts a lot faster only if I am "on track".

And with Dragon Dictation on the phone - every time you hit "stop" you have to wait while it sends the audio up to the server for translation before giving you back the text, which I feel compelled to edit before going on. But at the same time I wouldn't like to use a recorder, because I find the process of transcribing audio to be far too odious, and lacking the potential of being a true editing step because you have to focus on just typing out what you are hearing.

They have such different characteristics. I love hand-writing but prefer typing.. I feel that dictation should be the fastest but can't get into the flow.

**In what circumstances do the strengths of each method warrant their use?**

Comment: I'd probably rephrase this to ask something like "How do you decide whether to dictate, type out or hand-write a piece of writing?"

Comment: @Lexi, that's a really good idea actually. I wish I could rename the topic..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of those questions where everybody just has to go with their own personal preferences. My last choice would be trying to dictate. I tried Dragon Diction as well, but as you have already noticed, the pauses and the less than stellar word conversion rate make it too tedious.

I have done almost all of my writing by hand and then transferred to Word once I was ready to start editing and working on the second draft. I have tried to write my original work on the computer, but I find myself losing track way too often. I feel that by writing everything out by hand it allows my thought processes to work at a more natural pace.

For those who are into left-brain, right-brain comparisons, I read that handwriting is on the side of your brain that is more creative, while typing is on the side that is more functional. I don't know how true that is, but it certainly seems to work out that way for me.

Another advantage of doing my initial draft by hand is that when I get ready to start typing it, I tend to have a more critical eye on what is written down on the page. I am usually more focused on trying to read my handwriting, so I end up finding a lot more mistakes than I normally would by just reading the typed out version. Ultimately, though, it really depends on what works for you as the writer.

Comment: Hi Steven - and when you are writing long pieces, do you ever find yourself going back and making significant changes? Do you ever start thinking "oh, if I was on a computer, I could copy and paste that bit over there.."?

Comment: Nope, that is what the second draft is for. Also, I prefer to write to the end and then go back and edit as I type everything up. If I happen to think of ways to change a scene I will make notes in the margin and then move on. When I start to type it, I will make the changes, assuming I still think they need to be made.

Answer (score 3):

I oscillate between handwriting and typing. I find handwriting preferable for first drafts or for getting ideas out, as I can simply scribble on the nearest piece of paper or notebook, have arrows going everywhere - it's beautifully unstructured. I like it for first drafts as well for the same reason as Steven - it slows down my thought processes, which I find gives me greater insight to the scene I'm writing. Not to mention, there's just something *organic* about the scratching of pen on paper. It's definitely messy, though, and my pages are always full of scratched out sentences, inserted text and arrows everywhere.

However, if I already have a scene in mind and I know pretty much where I want to go, I will type it out. It's faster and I can get feedback more quickly and easily. I also use it when I want to braindump in a stream-of-consciousness fashion. Again, fast and easy to keep up with everything I'm thinking, though you end up with a huge block of text.

I've never dictated because I find it more distracting when it gets scattered words wrong. If we talk about just recording yourself speaking, I can't do that either as I need a visual medium in order to think properly.

As always, your mileage may vary.

Comment: I like the idea of writing as a visual medium a lot too.

As for dictation, I still have a fanciful idea that one day we will be able to speak naturally and have a transcription app quickly and accurately do its job without referring back to a server. In the right mind set, are we not just as imaginative speaking? With or without a few beers. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've been keyboarding for so many years that my handwriting has deteriorated past "chicken-scratch" into "hieroglyphics." If I write out a thank-you for a birthday gift, it's usually illegible by the third sentence. I literally *couldn't* write without a word processor. The flexibility and ease of editing, error correction, and brain-to-page is immeasurable for me.

However, sometimes when a keyboard is inaccessible (on the treadmill, in the shower, on the loo), I wind up coming up with entire scenes, sometimes whole pages of dialogue and narration, and I do wish I had Dragon available just to get it down before it gets away.

Comment: I don't think my handwriting ever progressed beyond chicken-scratch! That's why I have to take my time when I type it out, because I often find myself trying to figure out what I wrote! :)

Comment: I haven't gotten compliments on my handwriting since my first-grade teacher saw a page of my penmanship workbook (I think it was N) and literally gasped out loud in front of the entire class "Is this YOURS? I can't believe it!" and put five stars on it. I had never done anything so neatly before, and it's been all downhill ever since. :)